# How to identify the programming language for an android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, reverse-engineering

I reverse engineered an apk and found '.kt' files.So I assumed that android app was built in kotlin but when I saw the actual code there are no kt files but only java files.How is this possible?

Comment: Because you dont need to build an android app in kotlin?

Comment: An Android app can contain both .kt and ,java files

Comment: Maybe the decompiler you're using only supports generating Java code, but still understood that the original code was kotlin based on some metadata?

Comment: It's possible that the apk file linked with a library that was written in Kotlin, but that the App's code was written in Java.

Comment: Yes @NongthonbamTonthoi I agree that iot can contain both files but after viewing the source code ,not a single .kt file is found.